# perform action on link click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to perform an action on link click.In this case I want to call a method by clicking the anchor and not change the current site.

So You are on a site which is the news archive and now I want to delete a several post by clicking "delete Post".

After hours of looking for it on the WWW i dind't find anything whitout making use of a form.

is there any way to call a method by clicking and anchor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view:

```
<a href="<?=site_url("controller/delete_post/$post_id");?>">Delete this post</a>
```

Your controller:

```
public function delete_post($post_id)
{
   $this->load->model('my_model');
   $this->my_model->delete_post($post_id);
}
```

Comment: I suggest to avoid ShortTags in PHP see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use

Comment: Well, not really. The only reason you might be wary of using short-tags is because it _might_ not be supported on some servers. But my argument is: if you're not even working on a server with easy access to php.ini, short-tags is probably the least of your concerns... Always work on good shared hosts or VPSs.